# Download files/images with PNP Windows

Tags: windows, download, path, wmi, dslr

I need to transfer images from SD card inside a DSLR (Nikon) in Windows.

When I connect the camera I can access it as a camera in the explorer then find the SD card files, but I can't use this as a path for ie a Python or Powershell script.

The camera are managed by Windows as PNP objects, if I'm not wrong, and there is no "path" to access the files

There is little programs to import images from a camera to a specific path in Windows, then use this path for my script, but I don't have the admin rights on the computer AND the portableapps are not very reliable.

It would be great to find a way to access directly the files, does someone know a method to get it ?

EDIT: The camera are seen as WMI objects in Windows, I can access the DSLR with Powershell and Python with this solution:
https://python-forum.io/thread-13833.html

Powershell : Get-WmiObject Win32_PNPEntity | Select Name | Select-String "D7000"

it return : @{Name=D800}

with Python :

```
import wmi
import re
 
    c = wmi.WMI()
    wql = "Select * From Win32_USBControllerDevice"
    for item in c.query(wql):
        q = item.Dependent.Caption
        if re.findall("D800",q):
            print(q

)
```

Now I need to access OR copy the files/images to a "classical" folder, by Python or Powershell.  And my knowledges in Powershell/Windows systems are near zero, could someone give me some hints for this, please ?

Comment: Do you see the photo/pictures files in Explorer?

Comment: Yes, i have no problem in explorer, except that I can't access the files by a path and so can't access it in a script

Comment: If you see them in explorer and can open them in explorer, then you can get to them. What language do you use?

Comment: Hello, Python if possible, powershell if necessary